# Advice On Alternative To Using Many Dozens Of Check Boxes In An Asp.Net User Interface

Tags: gui-design, lists, checkboxes

I have a table that has 51 bit values to hold the values of statutes.

In production, this table would have over 10,000 records for the different LocationID's.

The UI for this in its pure database form would have a page with the dozens of text boxes.

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Any recommendation or links to how others have handled this situation ?